# Suffering succotash

Tags: idioms

According to this [website](https://idiomation.wordpress.com/2010/07/12/suffering-succotash/):

> In the mid-1800s, during the Victorian era, there was a rejection of all profanity and so the common people developed a wide variety of malapropisms to avoid swearing on Holy names. Soon, one could hear Cripes and Crikey replace “Christ” and Dangnabit replace “G*d damn it”  and Cheese ‘n’ Rice replace “Jesus Christ.”  The phrase Suffering Succotash replaced “Suffering Savior.”

Today the latter phrase is known only as an expression of annoyance and surprise by animated cartoon characters such as Sylvester the Cat and Daffy Duck.  Was the expression still in vogue when the Looney Tunes cartoons were made, or did the cartoons resurrect an expression that had already lapsed from the American lexicon?

Comment: I suppose it's *possible* the expression was used (on rare occasions) in the mid-1800s, but I'd have thought that would be largely irrelevant to it being revived/coined by cartoon characters later. Warner, Disney, etc., wouldn't want *any* of their target audience to see it as a "minced oath", since that would still be potentially offensive to some. Whatever - my guess is *sufferin' succotash* is a much more recent coinage, and your website is just making things up. Did ***any*** Victorian ever use *cheese and rice* "euphemistically"? I kinda doubt it, myself.

Comment: I think it was an invention by the WB writers. For what it's worth, Google Books does not report a single instance of the phrase (with either *sufferin'* or *suffering*) before 1965.

Comment: OED has a citation for *succotash* from 1876, but that's as a foodstuff not a minced oath. However the entry has not been updated since 1915, which predates Sylvester. But if it **had** been a minced oath before 1915 such a usage is likely to be mentioned, at least.

Comment: FYI, these are _euphemisms_. A _malapropism_ is a mistaken use of a similar-sounding word, not an intentional replacement of a taboo word.

Comment: It's sometimes hard to tell with Looney Toons.  For instance, Nimrod was originally a biblical name for a king and mighty hunter.  However, after Bugs Bunny's repeated ironic use of the name with reference to Elmer Fudd, it has come to mean a person of diminutive intelligence.  My guess would be that it was mostly invented by Loony Toons as succotash "sounds funny".

Comment: Not all the verbal banter of Everyman is documented, but this is clear: two non-existent published exclamations, *sufferin' succotash* and *suffering succotash* rose in popularity from the mid 60's and early 70's. That's almost 20 years after WARNER Brothers introduced *suferin' succotash* with Yosemite Sam, Daffy Duck, **and** Sylvester. I would wager Bob Clampett or Mel Blanc gleaned the phrase from Depression banter, when suffering people replaced meat protein in their diets with succotash.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not sure that the website I cited made this up, as I found the reference in several other sites about Sylvester, including Wikipedia, that made the same assertion.  None of them, however, gave a source for the suggestion that "suffering succotash" was a minced oath for "Suffering Savior."

Comment: @BruceJames was the idea that it was in the place of "Suffering Saviour" itself in doubt? I took that as a given, perhaps a consequence of a Catholic (as well as catholic) education.

Comment: OED's first citation for the "euphemistic" minced oath ***darn*** is 1781, Pennsylvania Journal: *In New England prophane swearing..is so far from polite as to be criminal, and many..use..substitutions such as **darn** it*. So such prudery shouldn't be pinned exclusively on the Victorians. But I'm far from convinced *"Suffering Saviour"* ever had any currency as an expletive, so it probably didn't need to be "replaced" anyway.

Comment: ...and maybe *"cheese and rice"* does actually predate [the 1998 movie 'The Faculty'](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cheese+and+rice), but I'd be very surprised if that "etymology" is over a century out.

Comment: I see the same claim about the religious origin of the phrase being made in about ten different web sites, but it is indeed *the same* claim, clearly copied from a single source.  I don't see it as confirmation.

Comment: [This book](https://books.google.com/books?id=Dd6bCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT142&dq=%22suffering+succotash%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiG2beHgdnOAhUCXR4KHfdUCZU4ChDoAQgdMAA#v=onepage&q=%22suffering%20succotash%22&f=false) claims that the phrase was in use (by Sylvester) in 1945, or shortly thereafter.

Comment: It should be pointed out that the expression was no doubt explicitly chosen because its sibilant nature highlighted Sylvester's very pronounced lisp.  Normally such a feature would discourage the use of a phrase as a minced oath.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "Cheese and rice" definitely predates that movie: I've encountered it in Rex Stout novels written in the 30s and 40s.

Answer (score 8):

I don't see any evidence that it was ever a common expression before the cartoon.

Minced oaths generally date back much further than the 1800s. Socrates and Aristophanes give us examples in ancient Greek, and several slurrings of oaths exist in English from the early modern period on.

They exist today too in people saying "gosh" and so on, along with a variation for lavatorial and sexual expletives (*sugar* for *shit*, *fricken* for *fucking* and so on). They tend to be often localised in form, with for example *jaysus* for *Jesus* only appearing in and around Dublin, Ireland (a pronunciation that would once have been used only in some Dublin accents being adapted by other Dubliners exclusively for non-religious senses) and various expressions coming in and out of favour as with local slang expressions one finds varying greatly around the world.

Because of the great variety in real use, and the added requirement for such uses in some media (where the writer is not allowed to have Sylvester the Cat say "God-damn that fucking mouse!"), and the fact that most writers are writers and writers like playing with words, minced oaths have a greater variety in fiction than in real life (though life often imitates art in this regard). Holy Inventive Phrasing, Batman!

As such, "suffering succotash" was likely used precisely because it wasn't very likely to be heard as an actual minced oath and that, combined with the chiming of /sʌ/ in both words, and so is humorous. Indeed, in this case it would not so much be a matter of the cat's swearing being replaced by a minced oath as with the *naff* of "Porridge" and the *smeg* of "Red Dwarf" (where we could expect expletives to be a larger part of the characters' vocabulary if allowed) but rather he uses funny minced oaths purely because they are funny.

Comment: Back in 1972 I knew a girl who used *"Smeggy winnits!"* as an exclamation, in contexts where I'd have been likely to say something like *"Fuck my old boots!"*. She explained ***smegma** = A sebaceous secretion, esp. that found under the prepuce* (that's the EOD definition), and ***winnet** = dog's penis* (I can't find that definition anywhere now, maybe it's a variant of US *wiener*, but I doubt it). Anyway, knowing that usage already, when I finally encountered the much later Red Dwarf usage I thought it was at the very least "pushing the envelope", if not positively "taking the piss".

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes, *smegma* was a popular insult around the more nerdy sections of my peers when that came out for similar reasons of being obscure, so it allowed quite a strong expression to hide as a made-up one much as *bollocks* and *wanker* allows US shows with a trans-Atlantic audience to be stronger in Britain and Ireland were broadcasting limits are more liberal than in the US, with the same word. *Naff* was once a Polari insult for heterosexuals, so "porridge" may have been doing something similar—Barker denied that, but he may have picked it up from theatre Polari subconsciously.

Answer (score 0):

Usage - "The Dick Van Dyke Show" - Season 3 Episode 21: "The Pen is Mightier Than the Mouth" (19 February, 1964) The character Buddy Sorrell (Buddy Sorrell) verbally reacted to Rob Petrie (Dick Van Dyke) announcing he was going to fire Sally Rogers (Rose Marie) by exclaiming, "suc-co-tash!"

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, but your post does not answer the original question, which asks whether *sufferin' succotash* was still in common use before the Looney Tunes cartoons were made, years before the Dick Van Dyke Show aired.

Answer (score 0):

When you think about it, Suffering is a star of on going pain, and Succotash is a an American dish. America is, as everyone knows a very religious place and there have been many other ongoing debates as to whether this 'catchphrase' was ever real. There was a rejection of Profanity in the mid 1800's, Victorian Age, so the common people developed a wide variety of malapropisms to avoid swearing on Holy names. They were used for swearing and other types of interjections. With time they came to have a mildly comedic effect.
People are not so concerned about blasphemy, nowadays. We have worse problems.

Crikey = 'Christ'
Cripes = 'Christ'
Jeez = 'Jesus' 
Dangnabit = 'Damnation"
by gum = "by g-d"
by gosh =" by g-d"
by golly = "by the name of g-d"
jumping jehosaphat
suffering succotash = 'Suffering Saviour'
 Proof of this came down to many, not many, but some recollected diary entries from young children of this time. Many people claim that their grandparents had told stories about such prevailer things and used the phrase 'Suffering succotash'. You may be sitting in your chai in bliss with a grin on your face thinking, this persons an idiot, people could have easily just said that even if it didn't happen. Well, if you dig a little deeper you find that currently 25% and up of the world still has no interest access. That's right an entire quarter has no access to internet and in many cases those which do don't have many people who can afford it anyway. And the funny things is that many people that remember these stories come from these countries meaning the chances of them knowing what the looney tunes are is rather small.

So to some this up in simple terms, for all those people out there that fell asleep halfway, Yes, 'Suffering Succotash' is a real thing that was used by many people throughout the mid 1800's and I absolutly LOVE the phrase.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I've removed your other "answer" which did not answer the question. If you would like to improve this one, you can [edit it](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/508093/edit). Corroboration -- citing your references you used -- would be welcome too.